# How to make an edit to an already published post back to Draft

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permissions

I have a marketplace using WooCommerce where the Vendors have their own set of products. Once they first create a product, an admin needs to approve and publish it for them.

The problem is that, once a product have been published, the Vendors can edit it and re-save with different content that very often is different from the approved one.

I would like to know how I can make sure that if they edit an already published product, the post goes back to "Submit to Review" or "Draft" status.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your **current theme's functions.php** file.

You have to replace **USER ROLE** with your user role name in if condition.

```
function check_edit_post($post_id){
 global $post;

  if( in_array('USER ROLE', wp_get_current_user()->roles) && 'product' == get_post_type($post_id) && 'publish' == get_post_status($post_id) && $post->post_date != $post->post_modified ){

     wp_update_post(array(
       'ID'    =>  $post_id,
       'post_status'   =>  'draft'
     ));
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'check_edit_post' );
```

Hope this will helps you.